# Nuxt Pinia State doesn't persist when set from middleware

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia

#### Describe the bug

This is my Pinia module:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
export const useStore = defineStore("store", {
    state: () => ({
        token: '',
    }),

    actions: {
        setToken(token: string) {
            this.token = token;
        }
    },

    persist: true
});
```

I set the state with `setToken` function from the middleware

```
import {useStore} from "~/store/useStore";

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(() => {
    const store = useStore();
    console.log('store.token1', store.token)
    store.setToken('token')
    console.log('store.token2', store.token)
});
```

Now on first app reload I would expect to see logs:

> store.token1
> store.token2 token

and on the second reload I would expect to see

> store.token1 token
> store.token2 token

Instead I see:

[image]

#### Reproduction

https://github.com/d0peCode/nuxt3-pinia-middleware-issue

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm having the exact same issue and have no way what the reason is.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Create a plugin to implement the middleware logic. There you could access the store values. Here is an example

```
import { useUserStore } from '@/store';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxt => {
    const store = useUserStore(nuxt.$pinia);
   // The pinia or vuex instant is needed in order to access the store instance outside setup()

    addRouteMiddleware('my-middleware', async (to, from) => {
        // TODO:
        if(store.isLoggedIn){
             // implement your logic
       }
    }, { global: true });
});

// for non-global middleware use this: 


  addRouteMiddleware('named-test', (to, from) => {
    console.log('this named middleware was added in a plugin')
  })
})
```